# Using limit laws while calculating the difference quotient?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, derivatives

I'm trying to calculate the difference quotient of $f(x) = x|x|$ to calculate to derivative at $x=0$.

Now when I try to do: $ \lim_{h\to0} f(x)=\frac{(x+h)|x+h|-x|x|}{h}$ it just seems too complicated to calculate.

I even tried this:

$$
\lim_{h\to0}{ \frac{x+h-x}{h}} \lim_{h\to0}{ \frac{|x+h|-|x|}{h}}
$$
Is this legal?

Even so, I still don't know how to calculate to right limit.

How do you calculate the difference quotient of this function?:|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall: $$|x| = \begin{cases}
x,& x \geq 0 \\
-x, & x < 0\text{.}
\end{cases} $$
Consider $$\dfrac{(x+h)|x+h|-x|x|}{h}\text{.}$$ Notice that
$$|x+h| = \begin{cases}
x+h, & x +h\geq 0 \\
-(x+h), & x + h < 0
\end{cases} = \begin{cases}
x+h, & h \geq -x \\
-(x+h), & h < -x\text{.}
\end{cases} $$
We have two cases here:
$$\dfrac{(x+h)|x+h|-x|x|}{h} = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{(x+h)^2-x|x|}{h}, & h > -x \\
\dfrac{-(x+h)^2-x|x|}{h}, & h < -x\text{.}
\end{cases}$$
Now, substitute $x = 0$ in both cases and simplify, and you will get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The really special behavior of this this function is at zero, so rather than do something for general $x$ and then “plug in” $x=0$, it's easier to start with $x=0$.  By the definition of the derivative, then by the definition of $f$:
\begin{align*}
   f'(0) &= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h} \\
         &= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h\left|h\right|}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} |h| = 0
\end{align*}